# Selecting which dtabse table to load from combobox in vb.net using MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm currently developing a Inventory System here in our company. I have 3 databases each database consists of 200+ tables. Now what I want to do is to load my table from my database through a combobox. So that when I select the Table name from combobox I will click a button to load it, so that i wont have to make hundreds of forms. So far, I'm able to show my table names on my combobox. What i'm lacking is what should I do to what I have mentioned above. Any reply/ideas will be highly appreciated. here is my code for fetching the table names:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
   Public Class Form1
       Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

      Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim myConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\IT-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MaterialsSectionISV2\Metal.accdb"
        myConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim schemaTable As DataTable = myConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})

        For Each dr As DataRow In schemaTable.Rows
            Combo1.Items.Add(dr.Item("TABLE_NAME"))
        Next
      End Sub
   End Class
```

Comment: So the tables aren't related at all? If they were, it wouldn't make much sense to create forms to view them individually. And why three databases? It sounds like the whole concept should be reevaluated.

Comment: Yes, they're not related. I used three database because I divided my Items into groups. TO be specific I divided my MATERIALS into three(Raw,Metal and Packaging). Before it's just a one database with three tables. But because the user want to have logs on Delivery, Withdrawal of material I have to remake the System. That's why I have made my Items as tables now w/c was just a field before.

Comment: Three tables or 200+? I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry. Before I only used three tables but now 200+.

Comment: OK, but why study these in forms? Only a database admin (you) would look at the individual tables for debugging or the like, and then the normal table view is fine or even mandatory. For users you would set up queries and task related forms using these queries as source.

Comment: Before I have 1 database(MATERIASL), three tables(RAW,PACKAGING,METAL) each table has 10 fields. But now since the end user want to have logs on DELIVERY,WITHDRAWAL OF ITEMS, I have to remake my project. SO now I have THREE DATABSES(METAL,RAW,PACKAGING). and on each database I have 200+ TABLES.

Comment: My end user wants to view the data in VB forms. Cause it's easier for them.

Comment: So you have 3 * 200+ unrelated tables? If so, this calls for a complete redesign. Are you aware of the power and features of a _relational database_ which Access is? If not, look up the topic - I guess hundreds of tutorials and this basic concept and how to _normalise_ can be found. Access is not a spreadsheet, neither when accessed from VB.NET.

Comment: What's a dtabse table?

Comment: Ok. I will check on it. Thanks @Gustav..